# How update the nested property in object (i.e Object also containing array of object) in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have below mock data based on object property need to update their respective value using spread operator. I am not able to do that because it is nested.

I am able to achieve using below approach but as you can see code line is getting increased. But we can definitely reduce use spread operator. Because in "title" property i am only updating 0 index and in left column only updating the label value rest of the thing is same.

```
const mockData = {
  title: ["Javascript", "Selected Topic"],
  leftColumn: [
    {
      key: "name",
      label: "Javascript Topic Name",
      type: "string",
    },
    {
      key: "id",
      label: "Javasctipt Topic Id",
      type: "string",
    },
  ],
};

const handleType = (val) => {
  switch (val.type) {
    case "Javascript":
      return {
        ...mockData,
      };
    case "Angular":
      return {
        ...mockData,
        title: ["Angular", "Selected Topic"],
        leftColumn: [
          {
            key: "name",
            label: "Angular Topic Name",
            type: "string",
          },
          {
            key: "id",
            label: "Angular Topic Id",
            type: "string",
          },
        ],
      };
    case "React":
      return {
        ...mockData,
        title: ["React", "Selected Topic"],
        leftColumn: [
          {
            key: "name",
            label: "React Topic Name",
            type: "string",
          },
          {
            key: "id",
            label: "Reacr Topic Id",
            type: "string",
          },
        ],
      };
  }
};
```

i am trying something below approach but not getting desired result

```
const handleType = (val) => {
  const newArray = [mockData];
  console.log("newArray", newArray);
  //   const index = mockData.findIndex((ele) => ele);
  //   console.log("index", index);
  //   newArray["title"][0] = "React";
  //   console.log("newArray ==>", newArray);
  switch (val.type) {
    case "Javascript":
      return {
        ...mockData,
      };
    case "Angular":
      mockData.title[0] = "Angular";
      return mockData.leftColumn.map((val, index) => {
          let value = { ...val, label: "Angular",};
          return Object.assign({}, value);
      });
    case "React":
      return {
        ...mockData,
        title: ["React", "Selected Topic"],
        leftColumn: [
          {
            key: "name",
            label: "React Topic Name",
            type: "string",
          },
          {
            key: "id",
            label: "Reacr Topic Id",
            type: "string",
          },
        ],
      };
  }
};

const type = {
  type: "Angular",
};

console.log("Angular", handleType(type));
```

Comment: Why did you say "need to update their respective value using spread operator."? Also, where is your example code?

Comment: If you're going to be overwriting all the properties from the object you spread later on in your object literal, then there is no need to spread the mockData in the first place

Comment: handleType() function is my solution. Since, in leftColumn array of Object only value of 'label' is changing and in title array only 0 index is updating.  I am just looking for some smarter approach

Comment: I'd write a function `generateMockData(type)` which then returns the wanted object structure, setting `type` at various places (`title: [type, "selected topic"]`). Anyways, this is too broad.